# Remapping commands in gvim

Tags: vim, dictionary, remap

I would like to remap the command  `<C-w> gf` to `gf`
How do I do that  ?

I tried

`:map gf <C-w> gf`

This is not working. How do I group `<C-w> gf` into a single action ?

Comment: Is there a space between `<C-w>` and `gf`? That should be removed: `:map gf <C-w>gf`.

Comment: Yes..There was! Fixed it by removing it.

Answer (score 4):

In short, you should remove the space between `<C-w>` and `gf`.

But I would recommend
`:nnoremap gf <C-w>gf`
because you use this in normal mode, and it's usually a good idea to prevent remaps unless you have a better reason not to.